# GLSL variables as main function params vs on their own line?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am learning OpenGL and GLSL. I was taught that the in/out variables should be formatted like this:

```
in vec3 something;
out vec3 somethingElse;

int main()
{
    // etc...
}
```

However, I ran across code like this online (ShaderToy):

```
int main(in vec3 something, out vec3 somethingElse)
{
    Is there a difference?
}
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Shadertoy code is used as part of a GLSL program for WebGL. There is additional code to make the GLSL program work that is not part of the Shadertoy code we write.

In Shadertoy, you will use:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord );
```

To output the image. Please notice it is `mainImage` not `main`. You can write a fragment shader in GLSL that has a `main` that simply calls into `mainImage` copied from Shadertoy passing the correct values.

For the code to work you will also need to define some `uniform`s to match whatever Shadertoy inputs you are using (`iResolution`, `iTime`, etc...), and actually passing them to the shade program.

To replicate the output of shadertoy you will also need a simple vertex shader, and in fact pass geometry that cover the whole view. *There is also the chance you do not want to replicate the output, but use the code in some other way.*

---

If you read the [Shadertoy documentation](https://www.shadertoy.com/howto), you will find there is also `mainSound` and `mainVR`. Of couse, simply adding to a fragment shader won't work. They will need their own additional setup to be useful.

Comment: If I am not mistaken that is an architecture choice of Shadertoy as they support also sound coded in GLSL.